# Wondering how to make an iridescent and slightly translucent object?

Tags: shaders, color

[image]

So I am trying to make a crystal in blender that has this kind of light translucency as well as iridescence within a certain color range. I'm pretty new to Blender so I'm sure it's something I'm just not very familiar with but I tried to kind of modify this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMiXPjwSkEo&t=25s)'s method to not much success at dialing in the color of the iridescent range. This type of crystal is called Sunset Aura Quartz if you'd like to see other examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a try (that works with both Eevee and Cycles), it's a mix between a *Diffuse* and a *Translucent* node, mixed with a *Glossy* that has a greenish color to get greenish reflects. Use a texture to get the streaks effect.

[image]

The image texture I've used:

[image]

Comment: This is great, thank you! So the mix shader goes directly into the surface of the material output, I'm assuming. Is that an image texture that you have attached to the bumps? It's slightly cut off so I can't fully see that node and that seems to be potentially the last piece that I'm missing with my attempt to recreate this. Thanks!

Comment: Yes I've edited my answer to show what kind of image I've used, I've just searched for "streaks" in a search engine

Comment: Thanks so much!